# How does Bind9 work as a private DNS, to get past URIBL Query Refused?

Tags: bind, internal-dns, blacklist

If queries to URIBL are blocked because URIBL "detects" that your DNS query is using a dns resolver ip address that has already made too many queries and exceeded the limit...

How does using a LOCAL DNS Service like Bind9, get around this?

---

My limited understanding is:

When a query to a URIBL provider is started,

the local Bind9 zones won't contain any records about URIBL

therefore it will need to go to a DNS forwarder to resolve URIBL
EDIT: my terminology was incorrect. Bind9 will query rootsrvrs for gTLD hints

but if your server's dns forwarder is 8.8.8.8 (a Google dns farm), 
and that ip address has already been refused from making queries to URIBL,

how do you get around this apparent catch-22?

EDIT: after learning how bind9 uses root srvrs, I removed the dns forwarder values 8.8.8.8 and nameserver settings of the mailserver, and bind9 returned an answer, because it was doing the lookup itself, not handing it to the 8.8.8.8 nameservers.

---

I have read at least 50 web pages about this, but none explain the details of how it is resolved.

---

EDIT: remainder of this question was deleted, it was superfluous, I will ask a separate question about it.

Comment: DNS queries are cached. This is not going around it, your local bind instance will just store in its cache the results it got from the upstream DNS it uses, and reuse it until it expires.

Comment: I think I understand that results are cached, but in this example, is my bind9 caching the "Query Refused" response? I thought it would only cache successful queries (even if query result was no record found)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused by how bind would work as a caching nameserver. A DNS forwarder really only comes into play when you're speaking from a client perspective, and isn't relevant in the context of configuring a caching nameserver. When bind is queried for a record it does not have, it follows the regular process of resolving the domain name, starting with the root servers. I found [this link](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/website-presence/online/how-dns-works/index.xhtml) to be a fun way of demonstrating what's going on with that process. You can also see the whole ugly process for whatever domain you are interested in - try it using `dig +trace serverfault.com`. What you see there will be the same resolution chain that bind is following. Once bind has received the results and assuming that caching is enabled for it, subsequent requests will be served from the cache until the record TTL expires, in which case it does that process again to refresh its cache.

So, if you set up a caching nameserver and you're attempting to query URIBL *through* that and it's being rejected, it's not going to be Google being rejected - it'll be your own servers IP. To confirm, try digging both nameservers - your own (`dig @<your_bind_server> test.uribl.com.multi.uribl.com`) and Googles (`dig @8.8.8.8 test.uribl.com.multi.uribl.com`), and see where the rejection takes place.

Also, no, bind should not cache rejections.

Comment: thanks, the verisign infog is cute, but it doesn't explain"Recursive", so I goggled "recursive dns query definition", and found this excellent explanation: https://www.slashroot.in/difference-between-iterative-and-recursive-dns-query, very helpful for future readers of this question...

Comment: thanks for the tip of +trace. I tried it with 127.0.0.1 and 8.8.8.8, then diffed the results, but did not see any rejection from 8.8.8.8 . They both recvd an A record value of 127.0.0.14 Therefore, I think the rejection is on the control logic at uribl.com, i will ask a separate question on how uribl.com knows the source of the recursive dns server making the query.

Comment: I was using terminology without knowing it's meaning. I was erroroneous in saying my local bind srvr was forwarding to 8.8.8.8. my webserver had 8.8.8.8 as it's nameserver value. yesterday I dug into bind's files, and found the root hint file, and concluded that bind would be doing the recursion by iteself and not using 8.8.8.8, so i removed 8.8.8.8, restarted bind, and i recvd an answer. but your explanation helped a lot thanks